# My update statement does not seem to execute

Tags: oracle, plsql

can you help me figure out what's wrong with my update statement? It seems that it's so slow in executing the update query itself. Here's the code:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT a.policy_id,
         a.peril_cd,
         NVL (a.ri_cd, 0) ri_cd,
          e.eff_date,
          e.expiry_date,
           (  NVL (a.premium_amt, 0)
            - NVL (a.treaty_prem, 0)
            - NVL (a.facul_prem, 0))
         * (e.numerator_factor / e.denominator_factor) def_prem_amt,
            NVL (a.share_cd, 0),
            NVL (a.item_no, 0) item_no,
            NVL (a.date_tag, 0) date_tag
    BULK COLLECT INTO vv_policy_id,
         vv_peril_cd,
         vv_ri_cd,
         vv_eff_date,
         vv_exp_date,
         vv_def_prem_amt,
         vv_share_cd,
         vv_item_no,
         vv_date_tag
    FROM GIAC_RECAP_CURR_DTL_EXT a, gipi_polbasic b, giis_line c, gipi_invoice d, giac_deferred_gross_prem_pol e  --added gipi_invoice by albert 01.25.2017 (GENQA SR 5848)
   WHERE a.policy_id = b.policy_id 
     AND b.line_cd = c.line_cd
     AND a.policy_id = d.policy_id
     AND a.policy_id = e.policy_id
     AND a.line_cd = e.line_cd
     AND a.iss_cd = e.iss_cd 
     AND e.extract_year = vv_ext_yy
     AND e.extract_mm = v_ext_mm;

  IF SQL%FOUND 
  THEN     
        FORALL indx IN 1 .. vv_policy_id.COUNT
        UPDATE GIAC_RECAP_CURR_DTL_EXT
           SET eff_date = vv_eff_date (indx),
               exp_date = vv_exp_date (indx),
               def_prem_amt = vv_def_prem_amt (indx)
         WHERE     policy_id = vv_policy_id (indx)
               AND peril_cd = vv_peril_cd (indx)
               AND ri_cd = vv_ri_cd (indx)
               AND share_cd = vv_share_cd (indx)
               AND item_no = vv_item_no (indx)
               AND date_tag = vv_date_tag (indx);
   END IF;
END;
```

Here is the information from the session browser of Toad:
[image]

It started to load the statement at 4:08 pm, but as of writing this(5:00pm) it still hasn't completed an execution. By the way here is the explain plan: [image]

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a bulk collect and not, say, a single UPDATE (or MERGE) statement? I mean, you're copying all the data from the query into memory (i.e. into the collection) and then putting it back into the database. Why not skip the copy step and let the database do the update?

Comment: Is it possible that one or more rows you're trying to update are locked by an uncommitted transaction in another session?

Comment: @AlexPoole that's a possibility, there is an insert statement prior to this update and the whole transaction is not yet committed. It will only commit once all functions are done. Perhaps I would try to commit the transaction first before calling this update. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Boneist Well I thought it would be faster if I use bulk collect instead of a single update, but I will try your answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @jeromecris - it would have to be in a different session, and therefore a separate transaction. (Maybe you tested part of the script elsewhere and left that session alive?)  If you insert and then update within one transaction then you won't block yourself. And if the insert and update are related then you probably want to keep them as one transaction with a single commit at the end - preserving atomicity.

Comment: @AlexPoole Ohh, sorry I if didn't understand your question. I think there was only one transaction running yesterday, and it was mine.

Answer (score 1):

You would see better performance by combining the select and the update into a single query, rather than pulling the data out of the database before stuffing it back in, e.g. by using a MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO giac_recap_curr_dtl_ext tgt
  USING (SELECT a.policy_id,
                a.peril_cd,
                NVL (a.ri_cd, 0) ri_cd,
                 e.eff_date,
                 e.expiry_date,
                  (  NVL (a.premium_amt, 0)
                   - NVL (a.treaty_prem, 0)
                   - NVL (a.facul_prem, 0))
                * (e.numerator_factor / e.denominator_factor) def_prem_amt,
                   NVL (a.share_cd, 0),
                   NVL (a.item_no, 0) item_no,
                   NVL (a.date_tag, 0) date_tag
           FROM GIAC_RECAP_CURR_DTL_EXT a, gipi_polbasic b, giis_line c, gipi_invoice d, giac_deferred_gross_prem_pol e  --added gipi_invoice by albert 01.25.2017 (GENQA SR 5848)
          WHERE a.policy_id = b.policy_id 
            AND b.line_cd = c.line_cd
            AND a.policy_id = d.policy_id
            AND a.policy_id = e.policy_id
            AND a.line_cd = e.line_cd
            AND a.iss_cd = e.iss_cd 
            AND e.extract_year = vv_ext_yy
            AND e.extract_mm = v_ext_mm) src
    ON (tgt.policy_id = src.policy_id
        AND tgt.peril_cd = src.peril_cd
        AND tgt.ri_cd = src.ri_cd -- should there be NVLs on the tgt side of things too?
        AND tgt.share_id = src.share_id -- should there be NVLs on the tgt side of things too?
        AND tgt.item_no = src.item_no -- should there be NVLs on the tgt side of things too?
        AND tgt.date_tag = src.date_tag) -- should there be NVLs on the tgt side of things too?
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.eff_date = src.eff_dte,
             tgt.exp_date = src.expiry_date,
             tgt.def_prem_amt = def_prem_amt;
```

You could improve the performance of this statement by removing the `giac_recap_curr_dtl_ext` table from the inner source subquery, although I appreciate this may not be possible.

Comment: Trying this. Thank you!

Comment: Update: Tried using the suggested query. Statement still does not execute. I tried using the FOR LOOP and the update was executed but it is running very slow.

Comment: What do you mean by "statement still does not execute"? Do you mean that the merge statement errors, or that it takes a long time? How long did you give it? Also, is it possible to rewrite the source subquery without the `giac_recap_curr_dtl_ext` table? You may want to add a where clause to the update statement part of the query to exclude rows that already have the right values, e.g. `where tgt.eff_date != src.eff_date or tgt.exp_date != src.expiry_date or tgt.def_prem_amt != def_prem_amt`.

Comment: Also, how many rows are in your `giac_recap_curr_dtl_ext` table?

Comment: What I mean is that after an hour or so, the value of the executions row in v$sql is still at zero when doing the update statement. I'll try to exclude giac_recap_curr_dtl_ext from the query and see if it improves. There is exactly  288,827 records on table.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on what v$sql is telling you until after the statement has completed. Also, please make sure the statistics on all the tables are up to date.